# Setting only a setter property

Tags: c#

I have an object model that has a property like this:

```
public class SomeModel
{
   public string SomeString { get; set; }

   public void DoSomeWork()
   {
      ....
   }
}
```

I want the `DoSomeWork` function to execute automatically after the `SomeString` property changes. I tried this but it's not working:

```
public string SomeString { get; set { DoSomeWork(); } }
```

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: what exactly do mean by "it's not working" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a private field instead, like this ...

```
public class SomeModel
{
    private string someString = "";

    public string SomeString {
        get { return this.someString; }
        set {
            this.someString = value;
            this.DoSomeWork();
        }
    }

   public void DoSomeWork()
   {
      ....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with automatic properties - you'll have to create a "manual" property backed by a field.

```
private string _someString;

public string SomeString
{ 
   get { return _someString; }
   set 
   {
        _someString = value;
        DoSomeWork();
   }
}
```

If you *really* can't deal with this boilerplate (say you'd have to do this hundreds of times), consider using an AOP framework like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) to implement this on your behalf - you'd  just need to declare an automatic property and an attribute to get the binary rewriter to implement the desired scheme.

Answer (score 2):

This will work...

```
private string _someString;
public string SomeString { get { return _someString; } set { _someString = value; DoSomeWork(); } }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private string _someString;

public string SomeString
{
    get
    {
       return _someString;
    }
    set 
    {
       DoSomeWork();
       _someString = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# team has introduced the auto-implement properties in C# 3.0. with the logic of minimizing the model making which is backed by an anonymous field created by compiler. this one is used when you don't need to implement any additional logic on a property of an object class. so it just followed as.

```
public string Name{ get; set;}// auto-implemented property. no additional logic.
```

if we want to add some logic as you want to add one function. we must be writing a manual property backed by a private field as like below.

```
private string _Name;
public string Name
{
  get {return _Name;}
 set {
        _Name=value;
        DoSomething(); //Additional logic implemented.
     }
}
```